# How can I fix my error in flutter about the API's?

Tags: flutter, dart

I got this error when I tried to display the data from the API and when I searched with AI I found that he said I should refresh the token but I think the API doesn't provide a refresh token because I tried it too. Can anyone help me?

> I/flutter (29366): Failed to load Bac info: Unable to parse error message with status code: 403

```
// ignore_for_file: must_be_immutable

import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class BacNotesScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String uuid;
  String authToken;

  BacNotesScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.uuid,
    required this.authToken,
  });

  @override
  _BacNotesScreenState createState() => _BacNotesScreenState();
}

class _BacNotesScreenState extends State<BacNotesScreen> {
  late Future<StudentBacInfo> studentBacInfoFuture;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    studentBacInfoFuture = fetchStudentBacInfo();
  }

  Future<StudentBacInfo> fetchStudentBacInfo() async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://progres.mesrs.dz/api/infos/bac/${widget.uuid}'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${widget.authToken}',
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final Map<String, dynamic> dataJson = json.decode(response.body);
      return StudentBacInfo.fromJson(dataJson);
    } else {
      // Include both status code and error message (if any) from the response body for debugging purposes
      String errMsg = 'Failed to load Bac info';
      try {
        final Map<String, dynamic> errorData = json.decode(response.body);
        errMsg += ': ${errorData['message'] ?? 'Unknown error'}';
      } catch (e) {
        // Failed to decode error message from JSON
        errMsg += ': Unable to parse error message';
      }
      errMsg += ' with status code: ${response.statusCode}';

      // Print the error message to the console
      print(errMsg);

      // Optionally, you can still throw the exception to handle it elsewhere
      throw Exception(errMsg);
    }
  }
```

and these are the needed data:

```
class StudentBacInfo {
  final String id;
  final String nin;
  final double matricule;
  final String nomAr;
  final String prenomAr;
  final String nomFr;
  final String prenomFr;
  final DateTime dateNaissance;
  final String moyenneBac;
  final String prenomPere;
  final String nomPrenomMere;
  final String telephone;
  final String adresseResidence;
  final String refCodeSexe;
  final String refCodeWilayaNaissance;
  final String refCodeWilayaBac;
  final String refCodeWilayaResidence;
  final String refCodeSerieBac;
  final String libelleVilleNaissance;
  final String libelleSerieBac;

  StudentBacInfo({
    required this.id,
    required this.nin,
    required this.matricule,
    required this.nomAr,
    required this.prenomAr,
    required this.nomFr,
    required this.prenomFr,
    required this.dateNaissance,
    required this.moyenneBac,
    required this.prenomPere,
    required this.nomPrenomMere,
    required this.telephone,
    required this.adresseResidence,
    required this.refCodeSexe,
    required this.refCodeWilayaNaissance,
    required this.refCodeWilayaBac,
    required this.refCodeWilayaResidence,
    required this.refCodeSerieBac,
    required this.libelleVilleNaissance,
    required this.libelleSerieBac,
  });

  factory StudentBacInfo.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return StudentBacInfo(
      id: json['id'].toString(),
      nin: json['Nin'],
      matricule: json['Matricule'],
      nomAr: json['nomAr'],
      prenomAr: json['prenomAr'],
      nomFr: json['nomFr'],
      prenomFr: json['prenomFr'],
      dateNaissance: DateTime.parse(json['dateNaissance']),
      moyenneBac: json['moyenneBac'],
      prenomPere: json['prenomPere'],
      nomPrenomMere: json['nomPrenomMere'],
      telephone: json['Telephone'],
      adresseResidence: json['adresseResidence'],
      refCodeSexe: json['refCodeSexe'],
      refCodeWilayaNaissance: json['refCodeWilayaNaissance'],
      refCodeWilayaBac: json['refCodeWilayaBac'],
      refCodeWilayaResidence: json['refCodeWilayaResidence'],
      refCodeSerieBac: json['refCodeSerieBac'],
      libelleVilleNaissance: json['libelleVilleNaissance'],
      libelleSerieBac: json['libelleSerieBac'],
    );
  }
}
```

So can anyone help me please because I couldn't find solution?

Comment: I'm not sure how we could diagnose a 403 w/ the information provided--a token is either valid or it isn't.

Comment: how to check if the token is valid ??

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the correct way of passing the token to the server see:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization and https://beeceptor.com/docs/concepts/authorization-header/

You need to check with the server to receive a usable token, tokens can get invalidated on the server without your knowledge.

There is perhaps an API documentation that you need to study to get going.